# How to realize explicitly an $SO^+(1,3)$ Lorentz transformation of $(x-y)$ to $(y-x)$ for space-like separation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, causality

Consider two spacetime points $x, y$ which are space-like separated. How can one realize explicitly a *proper, orthochronous* Lorentz transformation between two frames such that $x-y$ becomes $y-x$?

Note that if the time coordinates of $x$ and $y$ are equal, then this can be achieved simply by a spatial 3D rotation of 180° around the axis perpendicular to $\vec x - \vec y$. If the difference in time coordinates is not zero, one could do a boost by $\beta = |x_0 - y_0|/|\vec x - \vec y| < 1$ in the direction $\vec x - \vec y$ to set the time coordinates equal, and then do the rotation to flip the spatial coordinates. However, then executing the same boost again to also flip the time coordinates gives wrong factors of $\gamma$ and $\beta$ in the final result.

**How can one describe this Lorentz transformation explicitly either in matrix representation, or as a chain of boosts and rotations to give a proper, orthochronous transformation?** One possible matrix would be just $\Lambda = PT = \text{diag}(-1, -1, -1, -1)$ which is clearly not in $SO^+(1, 3)$. Is my aim even possible, i.e. is there an alternate description using the fact that $x, y$ are space-like separated?*

This question is for application in quantum field theory, where the non-equal time commutator of two real scalar fields can be expressed as $[\phi(x), \phi(y)] = D(x-y) - D(y-x)$. Since the propagator is invariant under $SO^+(1,3)$ transformations, the transformation described above can be used to argue that the quantum field theory is causal.

.* This image from Peskin & Schroeder page 29 seems to further make believe that this should be possible.
[image: Continuous Lorentz transformation for space-like separation (from Peskin & Schroeder)]

**EDIT:** This same idea is described in an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173629/78494) to a related question. To be more specific, here is my computation which doesn't quite work out. For simplicity, just consider a space-like 4-vector $(t, x, 0, 0)$ with $x > t$. (Any space-like vector $(t, \vec u)$ can be put into this form by a 3D rotation of the $\hat x$-axis into $\vec u$ direction such that $x = |\vec u|$.) Using a boost in $\hat x$-direction with $\beta = \frac{t}{x} < 1$, the time coordinate can be set to zero. This allows to flip the spatial component by a 180° rotation (e.g. around the $\hat z$-axis) which is in $SO^+(1,3)$ but has the same effect as $P$. Explicitly:

$ (t, x, 0, 0) \stackrel{\beta = t/x}{\longrightarrow} \left(\gamma(t - \frac{t}{x}x), \gamma(x - \frac{t}{x} t\right) = \left(0, \gamma(x - \frac{t^2}{x})\right) \stackrel{R_\pi(\hat z)}{\longrightarrow} \left(0, -\gamma(x - \frac{t^2}{x})\right) \stackrel{\beta = t/x}{\longrightarrow} \left(-\gamma t, \gamma\left(-\gamma(x - \frac{t^2}{x}) - \frac{t^2}{x}\right)\right)$

Note that the second boost is intentionally the same as the first one to give a negative time coordinate. One could fix the time coordinate by using $\beta = \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{t}{x} < 1$ instead, but this still wouldn't give $-(t, x)$ as a result.

Comment: What exactly about the "a la Peskin and Schröder" section of https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173629/50583 does not already answer this question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind In the second paragraph of my question, I've described the same idea as given in the answer you cite. However, if I carry out this transformation in the pedestrian way, I get wrong factors of $\gamma$ which don't seem to fully cancel. I can expand the question by my computation in a few minutes.