# Examples of the vacuum $| 0 \rangle$ break C, P, T symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, cpt-symmetry

Can the vacuum $| 0 \rangle$ of some QFT break C, P, T symmetry?

1. It could be that the **QFT break C, P, T symmetry explicitly.** Are there good examples?

p.s. The weak interaction breaks P explicitly and maximally, I believe.

2. It could be that the QFT does break C, P, T symmetry explicitly. But the **vacuum $| 0 \rangle$ of some QFT break C, P, T symmetry spontaneously.** Are there good examples?

p.s. We can also change the parity P to the reflection symmetry. Follow people's advice.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is your definition of "vacuum" where the vacuum is not by *definition* invariant under the full Poincaré group, and hence at least $P$ and $T$?

Comment: maybe take the weak interaction sector as an example, it does break $P$. And in our standard model, the vacuum $|0>$ includes the weak interaction breaks P explicitly. Agree?

Comment: I don't agree that the weak interaction not being parity invariant would mean that the *vacuum* is not parity invariant. You would have to spell out an actual argument for that.

Comment: The |0⟩ vacuum just means the lowest energy ground state of the QFT without any particle or operator insertions. I thought the weak interaction QFT partition function (without any particle or operator insertions), has the action $S_{weak}$ and the partition function $Z = \sum_{gauge} \exp(i S_{weak})$ already violates the P. This also means the vacuum  ground state  |0⟩ also breaks the P.  This is my view. Thanks for challenging.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That isn't correct, is it? We only strictly need to demand invariance under the connected part of the Poincare group. If the vacuum were still parity invariant, then any parity odd currents would need to have vanishing expectation. But wasn't the point of the kaon decay discovery that such amplitudes are non-zero (for CP rather than just P, but the argument is the same formally)?

Comment: @RichardMyers I'm not convinced this is true without someone spelling out the exact argument how non-invariance of the theory implies non-invariance of the vacuum. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591154/50583 where a similar question is discussed and the accepted answer points out a flaw in OP's reasoning by which they would have concluded that the vacuum is not invariant.

Comment: How about considering the ground state of a Ising magnet system? The Hamiltonian can be T symmetric, the ground state can choose to have different T breaking expectation values? This means the QFT lagrangian does not break T but the ground state |0⟩ break T?

Comment: example  physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228821/time-reversal-symmetry-of-transverse-field-ising-model

Comment: @ACuriousMind I see. Thinking about it more, I think I concede that I can't come up with a good argument if we aren't assuming such a unitary operator exists (which seems to be the point in the answer you referenced). The kaon example and argument I had in mind can be phrased in terms of identities between correlators, which seems to be strictly a weaker statement. It is these latter identities that a parity asymmetric action kills.

Comment: Prof. Michael Peskin answered part of my questions, see below.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the answer based on my conversations with Prof. Michael Peskin.

We both agree that there are QFTs that do not break C, P, T symmetry explicitly. But the vacuum |0⟩ of some QFT break C, P, T symmetry spontaneously.

There are many theories in which the weak interactions are fundamentally P and C symmetric, but P and C are spontaneously broken.  One of the original papers is

G. Senjanovic and R. N. Mohapatra
Phys. Rev. D 12, 1502 (1975)

Consider an  $SU(2) \times  SU(2)$  left-right symmetric theory of weak interactions, in which  $P$ exchanges the two $SU(2)$'s.   Postulate a set of Higgs fields in the representation  $(1,0) + (0,1)$  where the numbers are the isospin under the corresponding $SU(2)$.   It is easy to write a potential energy in which one Higgs field acquires a vacuum expectation value but both cannot.    The the parity symmetry is spontaneously broken.    The vacuum in which the first $SU(2)$ is broken is equivalent to the vacuum in which the second $SU(2)$ is broken.   In both cases, the unbroken symmetry is $SU(2) \times   U(1)$, which is just right.

Prof. Michael Peskin: "Some people writing in the stackexchange post   seem to be going around in mathematical circles.   They do not seem to have picked up a textbook to find out what spontaneous symmetry breaking is or what the actual properties of the weak interaction are."

Prof. Michael Peskin generously suggested: "So how can I help them?" Look at Prof. Michael Peskin's textbook Concepts of Elementary Particle Physics.  Spontaneous symmetry breaking is discussed in a physical way.

Comment: Prof. Michael Peskin does not have an account so we decide that I post an answer for him.