# $PT$ and Lorentz transformation and causality in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, commutator, causality, correlation-functions

This question was asked twice already, here: [A question about causality and Quantum Field Theory from improper Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112220/) , and here: [Causality and Quantum Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55687/). But I didn't get the answer to the question troubling me.
We were discussing causality in class, specifically for a scalar field with no interactions:

$$\left<0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]0\right>=D(x-y)-D(y-x)$$

Where we have the measure:
$$ [\phi(y),\phi(x)]=\int\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\delta(p^2-m^2)\left(e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}-e^{-ip\cdot(y-x)}\right).$$

The measure is Lorentz invariant and only depends on $(x-y)$, and there exist a transformation for spacelike separated events where $(x-y)\to-(x-y)$ and then it's easy to see that the measure must be equal to zero. That I agree, but what about the other method
where I can use an improper Lorentz transformations? As far as I know, Lorentz transformations are the transformations that keep the metric the same, this implies that the transformation $\Lambda=-I_{4x4}$ is a Lorentz transformation:

$$\eta'=\Lambda\eta\Lambda^{T}=-I_{4x4}\eta(-1)I_{4x4}=I_{4x4}\eta I_{4x4}=\eta$$
And here I didn't assume spacelike separation. Why is this not valid? Is the $\mathcal{PT}$ transformation not physical?

Comment: You forgot a crucial factor $\Theta(p^0)$, which is not invariant under $PT$.

Comment: @Zack I noticed that, but does that mean the measure isn't fully Lorentz invariant since PT are part of Lorentz group?

Comment: You have to be careful when someone says that a quantity is "Lorentz invariant". With the added factor of $\Theta(p^0)$, the measure of the integral is not invariant under the  full Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$, but only under the so-called "orthochronus" Lorentz group. This is the subgroup of the Lorentz group that preserves the forward light-cone.

Comment: @ Thank you so much! It makes total sense now!